# How to set up custom conversion event in GA4 based on item_id?

Tags: google-analytics-4

Im trying to create a custom conversion event based on item_id (SKU) in Google Analytics 4. I have a purchase event that correctly reports the number of purchases and the items purchased with item ids under the Montesation page in GA4.

Based on this, I want to create custom conversion events for different item ids so I can optimize campaigns based on purchases of specific SKUs.
What Im trying to achieve is a way to optimize campaigns for purchases of specific SKUs/item ids.

In the GA4 interface, I thought I could do:
Admin -> Data Display -> Events -> Create event -> Create -> event_name = "purchase", and item_id contains "SKU_XYZ", but that does not seem work. The new event does not show up.
It seems like it is not possible to create conditions based on item id, even if that parameter is shown in the list of parameters when you Create events based on other events.

Any idea how to achieve the above?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.